# Define F# '**' operator in C#

Tags: c#, f#, operator-keyword, exponent

I see that F# uses the `**` operator for powers, so `2 ** 5 = 32`. This is different from C#, where you have the option to use the '^' operator in your custom types, but for some reason isn't used by the built in number types.

But how do you implement the ** operator in C# for use in an F# project?

If I do this in C#:

```
public static Integer operator ^(Integer left, Integer right)
{
    if (Integer.IsNaN(left) || Integer.IsNaN(right)) return NaN;
    return left.RaiseToPower(right);
}
```

It compiles fine, and I can use it the same way as the '+' operator, but neither of these work in F#:

```
let intgr3 = intgr1 ** intgr2

let intgr3 = intgr1 ^ intgr2
```

And in C#, this doesn't work:

```
public static Integer operator **(Integer left, Integer right)
{
    if (Integer.IsNaN(left) || Integer.IsNaN(right)) return NaN;
    return left.RaiseToPower(right);
}
```

So how do I define the F# equivalent of the `**` operator in C#?
Thanks.

Comment: You can't define new operators in C# (`**` is not a built-in operator). I would suggest you put the `**` operator in an F# module.

Comment: Also, in C# `^` is logical XOR. Perhaps it is being mapped to that in F# (which is `^^^`).

Answer (score 7):

As I said in my comments, C# does not let you define new operators and `**` is not an operator in C#. `^` is an operator, however it is the logical XOR operator, NOT the exponentiation operator. This gave me a hint that F# might be translating your C# operator into native F# (`^^^` for logical XOR).

So, I created a couple test projects and using your definition of `^`, here's what I found  in F#:

```
open CSLib // CSLib is the C# library

let ( ** ) (x : Integer) (y : Integer) = x.RaiseToPower y

let x = new Integer()
let y = new Integer()

let a = x ^ y // error
let b = x ^^^ y // compiles, but looks like XOR
let c = x ** y // compiles
```

You can define new global operators in F#, however if you want this to be a general library that may not be acceptable.

You can define the Exponentiation operator for use in F# by defining a public static method `Pow` in the `Integer` type in your C# library:

```
public static Integer Pow(Integer left, Integer right)
{
    if (Integer.IsNaN(left) || Integer.IsNaN(right)) return NaN;
        return left.RaiseToPower(right);
}
```

Then, you are able to use it directly in F# as `**`. I will note that overloaded operators in C# are not idiomatic so having a `Pow` method will seem quite natural to C# users.

Comment: This is correct -- you just need to define a static `Pow` method in your C# class. To define overloads for other built-in F# operators, take a look at [`prim-types.fs`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L5350).

Comment: This is right, when I try the '^^^' operator in F#, it raises to a power. So should I stop using the ^ operator for power operations in my C# projects?

Comment: @AlexanderKvenvolden As a general C# user, I would not expect `^` to be exponentiation. Ultimately, it depends on what your users expect.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason why you can't define a ** operator for your object is that this is not one of the operators supported by the language. It's not a recognized operator..
Why not just use the Math library
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx

Comment: I am making a special symbolic number format and want it to be functionally equivalent to other number types in F#, including supporting all of the infix operators. If C# doesn't support it as an operator, is there a special name I can name the function that will hook into the ** operator when used in F# or something?